# Canvas draw : not able to render animation with runtime generated Bitmap images

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-canvas

Need a little help here : I'm out of ideas now...

Here's what I need to do :

- Render "base" image [ it is created from an ARGB.8888 byte array ]
- user clicks 2 points on the screen; I need to perform the the pixel manipulation on a region of pixels around the path taken from one point to another... [ I need to calculate a squre block of pixel for each pixel on the whole path ].
- display the modification of the image as the code progresses in animation form.

I am able to display the whole path; I am able to calculate & manipulate the pixels properly .. But what I am unable to do is show the animation as my code is progressing on the path... with the current implementation I am able to display the whole calculated path at the end ...

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
Paint p = new Paint();
canvas.drawBitmap(base,0,0,p);

traverse clickEvent1.x -> clickEvent2.x
      traverse for clickEvent1.Y -> clickEvent2.Y
           {
           newBitMap = calculateNewBitMap(base)

           // I nee to redraw Canvas with (newBitMap)
           // canvas.drawBitMap(newBitMap);

            //Doesn't work
            //postInvalidate();
            //invalidate()

            //AnimationDrawable.addFrame(newBitMap)

            // I am not calling start here 
            //but just wanted to let you know that I do call animation start to display the frames stored in it
            // animation.start();
           }

// obviously wouldn't work here As it is already out of the loop
//invalidate();
}
```

Please NOTE :

1. The newBitMap image is generated at runtime, it would not be available to me beforehand...
2. I tried invalidate() in the loop as well ; but it would only draw the cumulative result after the whole loop has traversed and not the intermediate states of the newBitMaps.
3. Performance is of critical importance + I am dealing with HUGE image sizes .. so please keep that in mind as well ... if I create multiple bitmaps for temporary storing the JVM crashes due to "OutofMemory" ..
4. I tried storing the new Images in "AnimationDrawable" form as well; but tht's not solving the problem as well....

   ```
   AnimationDrawable animDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();
   Drawable frame1 = new BitmapDrawable(newCaclBitMap);
   animDrawable.addFrame(frame1, 250);
   ```

Thanks for any pointers / suggestions ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you are doing is running all of your drawing logic in a single call to `onDraw()` when I think what you want is to have `onDraw()` called once for each frame of your animation.

So, instead of something like this in your trace:

```
onDraw()
  drawFrame()
  drawFrame()
  drawFrame()
  ...
```

You would have this:

```
onDraw()
  drawFrame()
onDraw()
  drawFrame()
onDraw()
  drawFrame()
...
```

The [CubeLiveWallpaper example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/index.html) has an example of this type of thing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to CubeLiveWallpaper ... I solved the problem on the lines of "LunarLander" & "cubeLiveWallpaper" implementations

Answer (score 0):

`Animation` objects are used to animate `View` objects. What you want to do is animate a canvas. This is more complicated but potentially more powerful.  Essentially you need to derive an equation that will govern the movement of you drawing as a function of time. When the animation starts you get the current time stamp and then in you `onDraw` method you draw what the canvas should look like at that point in time.  Basically you have to draw every step.